# I just want to have a validation for avoiding duplication of email address

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I just want to have a validation for avoiding duplication of email address. Someone please help me with this kind of validation? This is a simple registration with some validations. So, my target here is to avoid duplication of inserted data for email address.

Here is my updated work:

Here is my Sign-up code. The error is in my boolean isEmailExist which the (c) is cannot resolve symbol.

My goal is when there is an existing email address it will not be able to register again with the same email add.

In my database helper I check if the email is already exist but I have a hard time doing the coding in my Sign-up Activity

```
                boolean isEmailExist = helper.insertContact(c);
                if(isEmailExist)
                {
                    // notify user
                   //if the email add is already exist

                }
```

Comment: I don't see the problem. If you have a database to store previously entered emails, all you have to do is to consult to your database if the email entered is already in database!

Comment: Can you give some example on how can I check it in my database? thanks.

Comment: SO wont give you examples. If you have any problem implementing something SO will try to help

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether email address exists before inserting in to the table.

```
public boolean insertContact(Contact c)
    {
        boolean isEmailExist = false;
        db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        String query = "select * from contacts";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        int count = cursor.getCount();

        values.put(COLUMN_ID, count);
        values.put(COLUMN_NAME , c.getName());
        values.put(COLUMN_UNAME , c.getUName());
        values.put(COLUMN_EMAIL , c.getEmail());
        values.put(COLUMN_PASS, c.getPass());

        if(checkEmailExists(c.getEmail()))
        {
            isEmailExist = true;
        }
        else
        {
            db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        }
        db.close();
        return isEmailExist;
    }

private boolean checkEmailExists(String email) {
        String query = new StringBuilder().append("Select ")
                .append(email).append(" from ").append(TABLE_XYZ)
                .toString();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,
                new String[] { email });
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            cursor.close();
            return true;
        } else {
            cursor.close();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

And in your Activity:

```
boolean isEmailExist = helper.insertContact(c);
if(isEmailExist)
{
 // notify user
   Toast mail = Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Email Already Exist." , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT );
   mail.show();
}
else
{
 // proceed
 Toast password = Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Data has been saved." , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT );
 password.show();
 Intent i = new Intent(SignUp.this, MainActivity.class);
 startActivity(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the email column unique on the db, so that values will only be allowed once. On error alert requests user to reset password as the email they are trying to use already exists/signed up in the db.